# VIN OCR Dataset

Tags: dataset, ocr, vin

does anyone know of any labelled datasets including images of VIN (Vehicle Identification Number), or in German FIN (Fahrzeugidentifizierungsnummer)?

Or if not, are there any other datasets that could be used for the purpose of training an OCR model for automatic VIN reading? i.e. every VIN must have a san serif font.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.